# Modify PHAR file

Tags: php, phar

I need to modify a PHAR file. Whenever I make changes to the file and then execute it I get the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message SHA1 signature could not be verified: broken signature'
```

By doing some research I found out that I can either

- extract the phar, modify it and then "put it back into a phar file". How do I do that?
- or set `phar.require_hash = false` in my php.ini to disable the signature checking. This did not solve the problem unfortunately

I only have to do a few simple modifactions to the file and I'm the only one who is going to use it so I would prefer a quick and easy solution to the problem

Comment: Have you used your research? The second solution seems like the easiest; just add `phar.require_hash=0` to php.ini. Try things!

Comment: I added that to my php.ini but i still get the same error

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that on the Symfony website the install command looks like this:

```
c:\> php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony
```

The correct command is

```
c:\> php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony.phar
```

And move the file `symfony.phar` wherever you want to create your projects OR, just rename the file `symfony` to `symfony.phar`. If the file is named just `symfony` you will get this error "sha1 signature could not be verified broken signature" because changing the name of the file will also invalidate the sha1 (that's how hashing works).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply change the phar contents in an editor, just like you can't do that in a `.zip` or `.tbz2` file.

The only solution that will work is extracting the phar, modifying the extracted files and then re-packaging the phar file.